# Visual Studio cannot find SingleInstanceFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mediatr

I've missed something, but not sure.

I have included `using MediatR;`

and I am trying to register types using Unity:

```
//--------- External Dependencies --------\\
container.RegisterType<IMediator, Mediator>();


container.RegisterInstance<SingleInstanceFactory>(t => container.Resolve(t));
container.RegisterInstance<MultiInstanceFactory>(t => container.ResolveAll(t));
```

But VS is telling me it can't find `SingleInstanceFactory` or `MultiInstanceFactory`. The project is targeting .NET 4.5.1 and I am using the latest Unity, MediatR.

Latest MediatR, https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/Mediator.cs

I was just copying from the examples give by Jimmy.

Comment: What version of mediatR are you using?

Comment: Latest pull from nuget.

Comment: Are you sure `SingleInstanceFactory` and `MultiInstanceFactory` are defined in the `MediatR` namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest mediatR pull from nuget - https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR is 1.0.0

The factory method delgates you were referring to were not added until later - this changeset - https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/commit/82ce595fcd5d265862bf80127fee932902c3d8cd

You should get the latest source from main and build yourself.

Comment: Ahhhh, thats what I did last time - I remember now. I now know why I have a copy on my local! Thanks.